# Getting UK local authority boundaries in OpenStreetMap through R

Tags: r, openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries

I'm trying to plot some infrastructure data that comes from the OpenStreetMap using R. I'm using the `osmdata` package with `ggplot2`. I'm trying to pull the local authority boundaries of a few local authorities in Scotland, mainly islands in the west and north. I can't locate the local authority boundaries at an administrative level ("admin_level"). According to the OSM wiki, there appears to be a bespoke tag for local authorities. My question is: how can I use R to identify local authority boundaries for the UK?

My code, which returns zero features is:

```
### cycling through the admin levels 1:n doesn't provide the correct boundary 


outer_heb_1 <- 
      getbb("Outer Hebrides") %>% ## bounding box for Outer Hebrides
       opq()   %>% # build the Overpass query
    add_osm_feature(key = "admin_level", # Admin, level 4
                    value = "4") %>% 
  osmdata_sf() # return a simple features


### trying boundary/local authority in add_osm_feature
outer_heb_1 <- 
      getbb("Outer Hebrides") %>% ## bounding box for Outer Hebrides
       opq()   %>% # build the Overpass query
    add_osm_feature(key = 'boundary', # Admin, level 4
                    value = "local_authority") %>% 
  osmdata_sf() # return a simple features
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to download the polygonal boundaries from OSM using `osmdata`, I think you should check the argument `format_out` in `getbb()`. For example:

```r
# First of all, load packages
library(osmdata)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
library(mapview)

# Download boundaries
outer_hebrides <- getbb("Outer Hebrides, Scotland", format_out = "sf_polygon")$multipolygon
outer_hebrides
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -13.68751 ymin: 56.77795 xmax: -5.810481 ymax: 59.13431
#> geographic CRS: WGS 84
#>                         geometry
#> 1 MULTIPOLYGON (((-13.68751 5...

# Plot
mapview(outer_hebrides)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>